# Security cookie_secure CSRF not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, csrf

I am currently using Codeigniter and like to enable in the config.php:

```
$config['cookie_secure']    = TRUE;
```

I am also using:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = '***';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = '***';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

The connection is https only. But when I am using the cookie_secure option, the CSRF is not working any more and gives this:

```
The action you have requested is not allowed.
```

Codeigniter cannot store the CSRF in an cookie because of this measure. How can I solve it? I like to use both security measures.

<--- EDIT --->

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url().'login/'; ?>" method="post">

  <?php echo form_hidden($this->security->get_csrf_token_name(), $this->security->get_csrf_hash()); ?>
```

Comment: What version of CI are you using?

Comment: Also, do you actually have `***` as your token name? I am assuming not, but please put an example there.

Comment: Are you using the form helper?

Comment: Version 2.2.2 And the name = hg4dr3356H

Comment: Check [this][1] link. Do you use https protocol on website?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214612/codeigniter-csrf-error-the-action-you-have-requested-is-not-allowed

Comment: Is `form_open()` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue when I had both `cookie_secure` set to **true** and `csrf_protection` set to **true**.

What I first noticed was the CSRF cookie wasn't being set.

Looking at the `csrf_set_cookie()` function in `/system/core/Security.php`, you'll see:

```
/**
 * Set Cross Site Request Forgery Protection Cookie
 *
 * @return  object
 */
public function csrf_set_cookie()
{
    $expire = time() + $this->_csrf_expire;
    $secure_cookie = (config_item('cookie_secure') === TRUE) ? 1 : 0;

    if ($secure_cookie && (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) OR strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) === 'off'))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    setcookie($this->_csrf_cookie_name, $this->_csrf_hash, $expire, config_item('cookie_path'), config_item('cookie_domain'), $secure_cookie);

    log_message('debug', "CRSF cookie Set");

    return $this;
}
```

Though, like most, I use a load balancer for SSL termination. The individual servers don't know the traffic is over HTTPS, since the traffic is sent to each server over port 80 on the internal network. This is what the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` is for.

I ended up overwriting the `csrf_set_cookie()` in my `/application/core/MY_Security.php` to fix this:

```
/**
 * Set Cross Site Request Forgery Protection Cookie
 *
 * @return  object
 */
public function csrf_set_cookie()
{
    $expire = time() + $this->_csrf_expire;
    $secure_cookie = (config_item('cookie_secure') === TRUE) ? 1 : 0;

    if (
        $secure_cookie &&
        (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) OR strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) === 'off') &&
        (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] != 'https')
    ) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    setcookie($this->_csrf_cookie_name, $this->_csrf_hash, $expire, config_item('cookie_path'), config_item('cookie_domain'), $secure_cookie);

    log_message('debug', "CRSF cookie Set");

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this may handle the problem, make sure you have `form_open()` in your code. Per the [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) on codeigniter form helper,

> Creates an opening form tag with a base URL...

This should also add the csrf automatically without `form_hidden()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this CODEIGNITER BUG, you can set like below:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_projectname_session';
```

...

...

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = 'ci_projectname_';
```

As example above, cookie prefix and cookie name must begin as same.