# how to fix csrf in one page php ajax codeigniter problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3, csrf

I'm using codeigniter 3 and I've got issue here, how to fix my code if i use CSRF. because I want only have one page action to view in codeigniter.

**Here's my controller code :**

```
public function index()
{
    # code untuk menampilkan Database Rotator
    $this->data['partial_head'] = '
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="'.base_url('assets').'/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="'.base_url('assets').'/plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="'.base_url('assets').'/plugins/datatables-buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">';
    
    $this->data['partial_body'] = '
    <!-- DataTables  & Plugins -->
    <script src="'.base_url('assets').'/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="'.base_url('assets').'/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="'.base_url('assets').'/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="'.base_url('assets').'/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- jquery-validation -->
    <script src="'.base_url('assets').'/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="'.base_url('assets').'/plugins/jquery-validation/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script src="'.base_url('assets').'/dist/js/customJs/rotator-admin.js"></script>
    ';

    $this->data['content'] = 'rotator/index';
    $this->template->_render_page('layout/main',$this->data);
}

public function get_dataTable()
{
    # code untuk menampilkan tabel ajax

    $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));
      
    $query = $this->model->getAllData('rotator');
    $data = [];
    $no = 1;
    foreach($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = array(
            $no++,            
            '+'.htmlentities($row->nomor_hp, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"),              
            htmlentities($row->pesan, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"),                      
            htmlentities($row->jml_perulangan, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").' kali',              
            ($row->status_aktif==1)?
            '<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input btn-aktif" name="aktif" id="'.encryptor('encrypt', $row->id_rotator).'" checked>
            <label class="custom-control-label label-aktif" for="'.encryptor('encrypt', $row->id_rotator).'">Aktif</label>
            </div>':'<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input btn-aktif" name="aktif" id="'.encryptor('encrypt', $row->id_rotator).'">
            <label class="custom-control-label label-aktif" for="'.encryptor('encrypt', $row->id_rotator).'">Non Aktif</label>
            </div>',                 
            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle mr-1 btn-edit" id="'.encryptor('encrypt', $row->id_rotator).'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle mr-1 btn-hapus" id="'.encryptor('encrypt', $row->id_rotator).'"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>'
        );
    }

    $result = array(
        'draw'              => $draw,
        'recordsTotal'      => $query->num_rows(),
        'recordsFiltered'   => $query->num_rows(),
        'data'              => $data
    );
    
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit();
}

public function getByDataId($id = null)
{
    # code untuk menampilkan Data Himpunan jika tombol edit di klik

    $where = ['id_rotator' => encryptor('decrypt', $id)];
    $hasil = $this->model->whereData($where, 'rotator')->row();
    $data = [
        'handphone'         => $hasil->nomor_hp,
        'pesan'             => $hasil->pesan,
        'isAktif'           => $hasil->status_aktif,
        'diulang'           => $hasil->jml_perulangan,
        'id'                => $id
    ];
    echo json_encode($data);
}

public function tambah_data()
{
    # code untuk menambahkan data baru  

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('handphone', 'Nomor Handphone', 'trim|required|is_numeric|is_unique[rotator.nomor_hp]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pesan', 'Pesan', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('diulang', 'Jumlah Perulangan', 'trim|required|is_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('isAktif', 'is Aktif', 'trim|numeric');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        echo json_encode([
            'alert_error' => validation_errors()
        ]);       
    } else {
        $nomorHp = $this->input->post('handphone', true);
        $pesan = $this->input->post('pesan', true);
        $perulangan = $this->input->post('diulang', true);
        $isAktif = !empty($this->input->post('isAktif', true)) ? 1 : 0;
        $data = [
            'nomor_hp'         => $nomorHp,
            'pesan'            => $pesan,
            'status_aktif'     => $isAktif,
            'jml_perulangan'   => $perulangan,
        ]; 

        if ($this->model->insertData($data, 'rotator')) {                
            echo json_encode([
                'alert_success' => 'Data berhasil ditambahkan!',
                'status'        => TRUE
            ]);
        } else {
            echo json_encode([
                'alert_success' => 'Data gagal ditambahkan!',
                'status'        => FALSE
            ]);
        }
    }
}
 
public function edit_data()
{
    # code untuk mengubah Data 

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('handphone', 'Nomor Handphone', 'trim|required|is_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pesan', 'Pesan', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('diulang', 'Jumlah Perulangan', 'trim|required|is_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('isAktif', 'is Aktif', 'trim|numeric');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        echo json_encode([
            'alert_error' => validation_errors()
        ]);       
    } else {
        $nomorHp = $this->input->post('handphone', true);
        $pesan = $this->input->post('pesan', true);
        $perulangan = $this->input->post('diulang', true);
        $isAktif = !empty($this->input->post('isAktif', true)) ? 1 : 0;
        $data = [
            'nomor_hp'         => $nomorHp,
            'pesan'            => $pesan,
            'status_aktif'     => $isAktif,
            'jml_perulangan'   => $perulangan,
        ];   
        
        $id = $this->input->post('idRotator', true);
        if($this->model->updateData(['id_rotator' => encryptor('decrypt', $id) ], $data, 'rotator')){
            echo json_encode([
                'alert_success' => 'Data berhasil diubah!',
                'status'        => TRUE
            ]);
        } else {
            echo json_encode([
                'alert_error' => 'Data Gagal diubah!',
                'status'        => FALSE
            ]);
        }
    }          
}

public function hapus_data($id = null)
{
    # code untuk menghapus Data Himpunan

    $where = ['id_rotator' => encryptor('decrypt', $id)];
    $this->model->deleteData($where, 'rotator');
    echo json_encode([
        'status'            => TRUE
    ]);
}    

public function aktif_handphone($id = null)
{
    # code untuk mengaktifkan handphone

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('aktif', 'Aktif Handphone', 'trim|is_numeric');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        echo json_encode([
            'alert_error' => validation_errors()
        ]);       
    } else {
        $data = [
            'status_aktif'   => $this->input->post('aktif',true)
        ];
        if($this->model->updateData(['id_rotator' => encryptor('decrypt', $id)], $data, 'rotator')){
            echo json_encode([
                'alert_success' => 'Data berhasil diubah!',
                'status'        => TRUE
            ]);
        } 
    }
}
```

**Here's my table in view code:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable"
                                    width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                 <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>No.</th>
                                            <th>Nomor HP</th>
                                            <th>Pesan</th>
                                            <th>Jumlah Diulang</th>
                                            <th>Status</th>
                                            <th width="12%">#</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                </table>
```

**Here's my modal in view code:**

```
<!-- modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                <button type="button" class="close btn-tutup" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="" id="myForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="handphone" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Nomor Hp</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 inputan">
                            <input id="handphone" name="handphone" type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="13"
                                onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="pesan" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Pesan Untuk Admin</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 inputan">
                            <textarea name="pesan" id="pesan" cols="30" rows="3" class="form-control"
                                style="resize: none;" maxlength="256"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="diulang" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Diulang Sebanyak</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 inputan">
                            <input id="diulang" name="diulang" type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="2" minlength="1"
                                min="1" max="10" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <span class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">(x) kali</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-4"></div>
                        <div class="col-8 inputan">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                <input name="isAktif" id="checkbox_0" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
                                    value="1" required="required">
                                <label for="checkbox_0" class="custom-control-label">is Aktif</label>                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input id="idRotator" name="idRotator" type="hidden">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-tutup" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

**and here's my script code:**

```
//tampilkan data di datatables
$(document).ready(function() {
    resetForm()
    table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url: 'rotator/get-dataTable',
            type: 'POST'
        },        
    })    
})

$(function () {
    // validasi form sebelum di kirim
    $('#myForm').validate({
        rules: {
            handphone: {
                required: true,
            },
            pesan: {
                required: true,            
            },
            diulang: {
                required: true,
                min: 1,
                max: 10
            },
            isAktif: {
                required: false
            }
        },
        messages: {
            handphone: {
                required: "Pastikan masukan nomor telp dengan kode negara, misal 62xxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            pesan: {
                required: "Inputan pesan tidak boleh kosong!"
            },
            diulang: {
                required: "Input angka 1 sampai 10",
                min: "Input angka minimal 1",
                max: "Input angka maksimal 10"
            }
        },
        
        errorElement: 'span',        
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
            element.closest('.inputan').append(error);
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
        },

        // jika form di submit
        submitHandler: function() {
            var data = $('#myForm').serialize()
            $('.btn-simpan').text('simpan...') //ganti text button
            $('.btn-simpan').attr('disabled', true) //set button disable
            var url
            if (save_method == 'add') {
                url = "rotator/tambah-data"
            } else {
                url = "rotator/edit-data"
            }
            
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.status) {
                        toastr.success(data.alert_success)
                        $('#exampleModal').modal('hide')
                        reload_table()
                        resetForm()
                    } else {
                        var messages = data.alert_error.split("\n")
                        for(var i=0; i<messages.length - 1; i++)                    
                            toastr.error(messages[i])
                    }
                    $('.btn-simpan').text('Simpan') //ganti text button
                    $('.btn-simpan').attr('disabled', false) //set button enable
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    toastr.error('Error ' + save_method + ' data')
                    $('.btn-simpan').text('Simpan') //ganti text button
                    $('.btn-simpan').attr('disabled', false) //set button enable
                }
            })
        }
    })
})

//fungsi jika tombol tutup di klik
$('.btn-tutup').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    resetForm()
})

//fungsi jika tombol tambah di klik
$('.btn-tambah').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('.modal-title').text('Tambah Data')
    resetForm()
    save_method = 'add'
})

//fungsi jika tombol edit di klik
$('#dataTable').on('click', '.btn-edit', function() {
    $('.modal-title').text('Edit Data')
    var url = "rotator/getByDataId/"
    var id = this.id
    save_method = 'update'
    resetForm()
    $.ajax({
        url: url + id,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function() { 
                $('[name="handphone"]').val(data.handphone)           
                $('[name="pesan"]').text(data.pesan)           
                $('[name="diulang"]').val(data.diulang)
                if(data.isAktif>0){
                    $('input[name=isAktif]').attr('checked', 'checked')
                } else {
                    $('input[name=isAktif]').removeAttr('checked')
                }     
                $('[name="idRotator"]').val(data.id)
                $('[name="idRotator"]').attr('readonly', true)
                //console.log(data)
            })
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //toastr.error('Gagal baca data dari ajax')
            return false
        }
    })
})

//fungsi jika tombol hapus di klik
$('#dataTable').on('click', '.btn-hapus', function() {
    var url = "rotator/hapus-data/"
    var id = this.id
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Yakin akan menghapus data?',
        icon: 'question',
        showDenyButton: true,
        showCancelButton: false,
        confirmButtonText: `Ya, Hapus`,
        denyButtonText: `Tidak`,
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url + id,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(data) {
                    Swal.fire('Dihapus!', 'data berhasil dihapus.', 'success')
                    reload_table()
                    resetForm()
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    Swal.fire('Hapus Gagal!', 'Coba lagi', 'error')
                }
            })
        } else if (result.isDenied) {
            Swal.fire('Aman..!', 'Data tidak jadi dihapus.', 'info')
        }
    })
})


//fungsi untuk aktivasi handphone
$('#dataTable').on('click', '.btn-aktif', function() {
    var url = "rotator/aktif-handphone/"
    var id = this.id
    var aktif = $('input#'+ id +':checked').val() ? '1' : '0'    
    $.ajax({
        url: url + id,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data : {aktif:aktif},
        success: function(data) {
            toastr.success(data.alert_success)
            reload_table()
        },        
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            toastr.error(data.alert_error)
            return false
        }
    })            
})

//fungsi untuk reload dataTabel
function reload_table() {
    table.ajax.reload(null, false)
}

//fungsi untuk cek hanya angka yang diinput
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {        
        return false        
    }
    return true
}

//fungsi untuk reset form
function resetForm() {
    $('#myForm').find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked') //kosongkan chekbox
    $('#myForm').find('input:text').val('') //kosongkan form input
    $('#myForm').find('textarea').text('') //kosongkan text area
}
```

if I try to setting my `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;` will be error and showing notification, Where location we must locate `<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>` and `<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>` to fix all ajax using csrf in one page..?

Comment: are you use multi form see this answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407364/6559546)

Answer (score 0):

i come across this issue and if are you use multi form see this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407364/6559546