# how send file with ajax in codeigniter framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload, csrf

I have problem with csrf in codeigniter framework when i want to send file ajax type must :

```html
   var file = document.getElementById("sortpicture");
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);
   
   var csrf_name = $("input[name=csrf_name]").val();
   var csrf_token = $("input[name=csrf_token]").val();
   console.log(formData);
   var dataObj = {};
   dataObj[csrf_name]=csrf_token;
   //dataObj['file']=formData;
```

```html
    $.ajax({
                url: "/uploads",
                dataType: 'script',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function(){
                    alert("works"); 
                }
     });
```

But When i use data like

```html
data {<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?> : <?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>},
```

It must ignore  contentType: false,  processData: false, to reslove then i can't send file now :(

I am tried to search how send file with ajax in codeigniter framework

thank you everyone :)

Comment: Whats an error are you getting within it define it

Comment: The action you have requested is not allowed

Comment: Have you checked your answer somewhere else just check this link if it works for you [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367096/csrf-token-problem-with-codeigniter?rq=1), [Link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214612/codeigniter-csrf-error-the-action-you-have-requested-is-not-allowed) revert me back if you found your answer over there

Comment: Yes , i saw it :) i can send any text message to ci when don't use contentType , processData in ajax(jqery method ) but in fromData when disable this method i got error from jquery :(

Comment: You could do this manually as well by adding the token as a hidden input field in the form
`<input type="hidden" name="csrf_hash_name" value="your-hash-value-here">` let's see if it works

Comment: I have these let me update code then see it

Comment: problem is not crf token name or hash problem is file data not able to send

Comment: You have console.log(form_data) are you getting form_data, if Yes then in which format

Comment: i have form data but i can't send form data and csrf both if i send these together i must commet content type and porecces data then form data not valid to be send ( i get error ) (javascript error I mean)

Comment: Then try to send form data individually by passing reference parameter

Comment: form_data is object when you want send it none varibale can't send it in array :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Action you have requested is not allowed error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383483/action-you-have-requested-is-not-allowed-error)