# codeigniter CSRF error

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, csrf

I'm trying to use codeigniter with CSRF protection enabled. I've read the already answered solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367096/csrf-token-problem-with-codeigniter?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214612/codeigniter-csrf-error-the-action-you-have-requested-is-not-allowed) But that didnt seem to resolve the issue. At some point the `"Action you requested is not allowed"` error is solved, but now it doesnt load the form validation helper. It throws 'Unable to load the requested file: helpers/form_validation_helper.php` What must have gone wrong?

Here's the controller file:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
}

public function index(){
    $data['title'] = "Home";
    $data['main_content'] = 'frontend/index'; 
    $this->load->view("frontend/includes/template", $data);
}

public function contact(){
    $data['title'] = "Contact Us";
    $data['main_content'] = 'frontend/contact';
    $this->load->view('frontend/includes/template', $data);
}

//submit functions
public function contact_submit(){
    $send_clicked = $this->input->post('sub');
    if(isset($send_clicked)){

        $this->load->helper('date');
        $this->load->helper('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|max_length[40]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject', 'trim|required|max_length[100]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'trim|required|max_length[1000]|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        } else {

            $clean_name = $this->input->post('name');
            $clean_email = $this->input->post('email');
            $clean_subject = $this->input->post('subject');
            $clean_message = $this->input->post('message');
            $date = now();

            $db_data = array(
                'name' => $clean_name, 
                'email' => $clean_email, 
                'subject' => $clean_subject, 
                'message' => $clean_message, 
                'date_posted' => $date
                );

            print_r($db_data);
        }
    }
}

public function page_missing(){
    $data['title'] = "404 Page Missing";
    $data['main_content'] = 'frontend/404'; 
    $this->load->view("frontend/includes/template", $data);
}

}
```

Here's some configs of config.php that i made changes to:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'qtd_sess';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'qtd_sess';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;

$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;

$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

Here some part of the view:

```
<!-- Start Contact Form -->
        <?php $attributes = array('class' => 'contact-form', 'id' => 'contact-form');
         echo form_open('home/contact_submit', $attributes); ?>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" class="requiredField" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

            <div class="controls">
              <textarea rows="7" placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" id="submit" name="sub" class="btn-system btn-large">Send</button>
          <div id="success" style="color:#34495e;"></div>
        </form>
        <!-- End Contact Form -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form validation is not a helper. Its a library.

```
$this->load->helper('form_validation');// this is wrong

$this->load->library('form_validation');// this is correct.
```

for more information see [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html)

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: Ahh... silly mistake. Thanks @NiranjanNRaju Would keep this in mind.

Comment: Sure... Glad it helped you:)