# NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-405

I receive the above error no matter what link I go to in my current development project, using CodeIgniter 3.0.6, and MaterializeCSS.

Searches for this error on SO and Google does not bring up any answers for me.

There does not seem to be any way to trace this further. My Apache 2.4.x error logs is not showing errors, only Firebug.

Any idea what could be wrong?

**Edit**: This does not seem to have any effect on the functionality of my site besides the error in Firebug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery plugin that dealt with the onepage navigation caused it. When I removed that plugin, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you enabled CSRF protection.
If the hash expires on server side, your client sends the wrong hash to the server. 
If the client hash and the server hash are not the same CI will send this error message to the client.

This may will help you:
[codeigniter CSRF error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140381/codeigniter-csrf-error)

Comment: Hi @Shardas Thanks for your answer, but no, it even happens on pages without forms. I ahve furthermore switched off CSRF protection.